# How to create a live stream player in WebOS for play M3U playlist (IPTV)?

Tags: live, television, webos, lg, m3u

I'm trying to develop an app for LG WebOS TVs.

The app should list the content of an M3U URL with some live stream. WebOS uses HTML and Javascript, I tried using the video tag, but it doesn't work with the playlist url, and it doesn't work with a live stream url, it only works with a non-live url.

There is not much information about live stream for WebOS on the LG website, nor on the official WebOS website.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Hi, do you found any solution on how to work with live streaming in Lg WebOs?

Comment: Not yet, if you know please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="player" autoplay="autoplay" crossorigin="anonymous" width="1920" height="1080" data-setup="{}"></video>

    <script>
    if( Hls.isSupported() ) {
        var oAvPlayer = document.getElementById('player');
        var oHlsApi = new Hls();
        oHlsApi.subtitleDisplay = false;
        oHlsApi.attachMedia(oAvPlayer);

        // Play channel
        oHlsApi.loadSource('https://rakuten-spotlight-3-eu.rakuten.wurl.tv/playlist.m3u8');
        oHlsApi.startLoad();
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```